# How to convert the ist to est date and time format using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I trying to convert the current date 5/3/2018 to Mon Mar 5 01:54:07 EST 2018 this format using angularjs before sending to the backend i need to convert this format

Comment: Maybe you can use https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I need example for that .........I am using the html5 input type date

Comment: momentjs.com has a lot of examples. What did you find?

Comment: I am using html5 input type date how i will use momentjs

Comment: example: https://codepen.io/naimad/pen/mxdvrB

Comment: Thanku so much but  EST is not displaying there but input date should select current date

Comment: I updated example: https://codepen.io/naimad/pen/mxdvrB

Answer (score 0):

var DATE_RFC2822 = moment().format("ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss ha z YYYY");